# How to warn two attributes with the same name in VS Code, Python?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

PyCharm will warn this code `Redeclared 'param1' defined above without usage`.

```py
class MyParam:
    param1 = '1'
    param1 = '2'
```

This is very useful, since it notifies me the mistake.

However, with the same code on VS Code, I got no warning. Could you please show me how to get it?

By the way, I am using `flake8`, `pylint`, and `black` on VS Code.

Thanks.

Comment: it is valid Python, so no need to report a warning/error

Comment: Hi @rioV8, thanks for your comments. However, I disagree with you. Not all valid Python syntax should be encouraged, especially for complex projects. If you define `a=1` but never use `a` in your code, both PyCharm and VS Code will warn you. My case should be warned too, which is already done in PyCharm but not yet in VS Code.

Comment: if you write decorator syntax with assignments you can get the same multiple assignments on class level and that **is** valid Python, assigning and not using is a different kind of warning, why calculate/keep something when you don't use it.

Comment: if you like PyCharm over VSC use PyCharm, or use PyCharm for a final lint check, the same with gcc, clang, vs-C++ they also do not complain about the same stuff